# Python / pandas - convert conditional hours to minutes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some working code to convert hours to minutes (with a condition on the hour value) but I'm currently iterating over the dataframe rows and that doesn't seem very efficient for larger dataframes

I have 2 pandas series (in reality these are columns of a larger dataframe):

```
hours = pd.Series([0,10,15,20,30])
mins = pd.Series([10,0,0,20,10])
```

What I want to do is the following:

- Return a single series containing the total duration in minutes (i.e. convert hours to minutes, then add to the minute value)
- If the hour value is 15, 30, 45, 60 or 90, directly add it to the minute value without hour-minute conversion, then set hours to 0. Else, convert hours to minutes, then do the addition

I'm expecting the output to be the following series (note indices 2 and 4):

```
0      10.0
1     600.0
2      15.0
3    1220.0
4      40.0
```

I wrote the following function that achieves what I want:

```
def convert_time(hours, minutes):
    df_duration = pd.DataFrame({"hours": hours, "minutes": minutes}).astype(float)
    series_converted = pd.Series()

    # Replace nan with zero
    df_duration = df_duration.fillna(0)

    # Convert out of bound hour values, add to minutes
    for i in range(df_duration.shape[0]):
        if df_duration.iloc[i]["hours"] in (15,30,45,60,90):
            cur_hours = 0
            cur_mins = df_duration.iloc[i]["hours"] + df_duration.iloc[i]["minutes"]
        else:
            cur_hours = df_duration.iloc[i]["hours"]
            cur_mins = df_duration.iloc[i]["minutes"]

        series_converted.set_value(i,(cur_hours * 60) + cur_mins)

    return series_converted
```

Whats the correct way to do this in Pandas without iterating over dataframe rows? I can't seem to figure out how to use pandas masking across 2 columns when a condition is involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `where` with `isin` to only perform the conversion where the values are not in the list of values you want, then you can `fillna` with the normal operation:

```
In [134]:
(hours.where(~hours.isin([15,30,45,60,90])) * 60 + mins).fillna(hours + mins)

Out[134]:
0      10.0
1     600.0
2      15.0
3    1220.0
4      40.0
dtype: float64
```

You can see this broken down:

```
In [135]:   
hours.isin([15,30,45,60,90])

Out[135]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

In [136]:
~hours.isin([15,30,45,60,90])

Out[136]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool

In [138]:
hours.where(~hours.isin([15,30,45,60,90]))

Out[138]:
0     0.0
1    10.0
2     NaN
3    20.0
4     NaN
dtype: float64

In [139]:
(hours.where(~hours.isin([15,30,45,60,90])) * 60 + mins)

Out[139]:
0      10.0
1     600.0
2       NaN
3    1220.0
4       NaN
dtype: float64
```